# Laravel Scout not finding any records

Tags: php, laravel, indexing, laravel-scout

I am using A Search Bar Form which searches in a database of +-175.000 Models. I've installed Scout accordingly to the documentation and imported all the records using `scout:import`.

Now, I've setup a function in my Controller to do the search and return all Records, but the records are always empty, regardless for what I search.

web.php:

```
Route::post('/act/search', ['uses' => 'ActController@searchAct', 'as' =>'searchAct']);
```

ActController@searchAct:

```
public function searchAct(Request $request)
{
    $actes = Act::search($request->search)->paginate(100);
    return view('act')->with('actes', $actes);
}
```

The form:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="{{ route('searchAct') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

As far as I see this should work but `dd($actes)` say that the collection is empty. I've included the `use Searchable;` Entrait in my Model. Scout index the records fine: All `[App\Act]` records have been imported.

Comment: Thank you @Pierre Lebon. Btw, is there an easy way to remove trailing spaces on SO?

Comment: I use N++ as Post editor. In N++, Ctrl+A > Edit Menu > Blank Operation > Trim Trailing Space. Bonus: Blank Operation > Tab to Space is the key to have good indented code.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that there is no index file created. I'm using Homestead. Theres no index file on my windows machine in the storage folder.

Comment: Do you have a job-runner for background tasks?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a few days ago and as previously mentioned in one of the comment above, `laravel-scout` wasn't generating the index file but I couldn't figure out why. Maybe the folks that built the package intended it that way for performance reasons.

Anyway in my own case I ended up integrating [TNTSearch](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver)  available [here](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver) (with an easy to understand documentation) to do the indexing for me.